# Silent Error in jQuery UI datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker, daterangepicker

I have encountered a very strange problem.

I am building a reporting package and part of it uses the [daterangepicker](http://www.filamentgroup.com/.../date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/) library to, well, pick a date range. However, during the function that creates everything, it just stops once it gets to the creation call `$("#date-range-picker").daterangepicker(options)`. After some time tracing the calls through daterangepicker, jQuery, and jQueryUI, I discover that a call to `new Date()` is failing with the error `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, and it seems that the code inside just stores the error and still thinks its a Date object.

I tested creating a new date while the script was paused there and it caused the same error.
The same error happens once the script has fails. But not before the script starts.

**UPDATE:** I found the problem, it was a repetition of the daterangepicker script include.

Comment: drum-roll! a stackoverflow, to bad the question already has 5 tags..

Comment: Is there any other script on that page that may be causing the problem?

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem that I can close it without deleting it.
Anyway, I found the problem, it was a duplication of the daterangepicker script. Though the script error didn't exactly lead me to that conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

use dynamic IDs for datepicker if you use datepicker more than one time at same page.

```
$(".any_class").live({

     focus: function(){ 
         var id = $(this).attr("id");
        $( "#"+ id ).datepicker({
        numberOfMonths: 1, 
        yearRange: '1960:2020',
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        showButtonPanel: false,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        onClose: function(){ /*anything on close*/ }

        });
        }  
    });
```